# How to browse the iCloud backups?

Tags: icloud, backup

Recently my iCloud backup for my iPhone SE has grown and my 5GB free iCloud is almost full.

Is there a way to view what is included in the backup, to find the biggest items, and possibly remove them?

Note: I don't have a Mac computer.

About the duplicate: That question is about the next backup and it's size, this one is about the existing backup on iCloud. This are two different. My "Next Backup Size" is a mere 64 MB.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/115715/icloud-has-space-but-icloud-backup-says-that-i-dont-have-enough-to-complete-a-b

Comment: @ankii that question begins with "iCloud has space", while in my case it is "iCloud is almost full" (actually it is 100% full)

Comment: but it still gives hints about where to look. If your doubt is cleared, even in the question, I'd support the closure. If not, do clarify, *how that question doesn't help you*, rather than *how these are different*.

Comment: Unlike Time Machine, an iOS iCloud backup is always a snapshot. So if you want to reduce the size of the backup, change the content of the next backup and then trigger a backup.