# "This iPhone cannot be backed up because there is not enough iCloud storage available", but there is almost nothing in iCloud (260MB of 5GB used)

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, backup

I cannot do the backup, the message on the iCloud backup page says:

> This iPhone cannot be backed up because there is not enough iCloud storage available

but I removed almost everything from my iCloud, so on the storage page, I can see 260MB out of 5GB used (so almost nothing is occupied). What is the point here? How can I use iCloud? Apple is removing the free iCloud option, is this really true?

Comment: To whomever downvoted my question: That's all you can do! You can downvote my question and think high of yourself. Let's see if I will be in plus or minus with this question, because that's what counts :) keep your eyes on the vote meter :)

Comment: Hi Vladimir. I’ll get an answer but you asked several questions. That’s almost always worth a down vote in my book for someone that understands the site expectations like you. I could not fault others for voting and not commenting since you attack people for having an opinion in your current comment.

Comment: Just been on Apple.com and 5GB is still free for iCloud. iCloud+ has paid variations.

Comment: @VladimirDespotovic Not sure what your propblem is here?  You have the fre 5gb iCloud plan, but your backup doesn't fit within 5 gb.  Is there some reason you think it should?

Comment: Everything clear :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an open case with Apple on my phone. It’s saying it needs more space than it has. (Can’t back up to cloud which has twice the space of the phone total free and can’t back up to Mac with twice the storage free.)

I think there’s a software bug in play [once you’ve ruled out that your next / total backup should fit In 5 GB of free space](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/115717/5472) (or your cap if higher). I would encourage you to open a support case as only Apple can sort and fix this sort of bug / error.

I presume you found and followed the KB on backing up your phone.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203977

I’ll also presume you checked storage and have enough for your selection of data to be backed up.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203516